# Adding Custom UI to a Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

So I want to create a UIElement which will act like a graph. I could add specific points to the graph and it will be rendered on the screen. For ease I want to be able to just add it to my canvese children like so:

this.InkCanvas.Children.Add(this.MainGraph);

So my question is can I somehow do this and if yes then how.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the Chart control from [WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/)?

If you want to do it yourself, you'll need to create a custom control. There's a nice tutorial on [Tim Heuer's blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx) to get you started. You might also want to take a look at the [sources](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/Charting/Chart/Chart.cs) of the Chart control from WinRT XAML Toolkit.